# Blender lock Ik rotation not working

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm some sort of a mechanical creature in Blender and I have an issue with locking the rotation.

I have locked every bones rotation on the axis i want to and in the resting position the leg is completely straight:
[image]

But when i bend the leg, the leg isn't perfectly straight anymore:
[image]

This wouldn't be a big issue, but since it's a mechanical creature with joints that are only supposed to rotate on a certain axis, it just wouldn't make sense to leave it like this.

any suggestions? I'm a total noob at rigging etc.

Comment: without seeing any settings - we can just guess. Since your are a beginner - please provide blend file to provide a quicker answer than asking in the comments thing by thing what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IK Rot lock is referred to local bone's axis, which is different from world coordinates. Enable bones axis visualization and double check if you locked the correct axis for every bone: Pose the IK target in a bending location and start locking every axis of every bone (the leg shouldn't move at all); then unlock the correct axis one by one, statrting from the tip, to spot where the problem lies.

[image]

Comment: I fixed it by re-making the armature. I believe i had rotated the armature 90 degrees right after creating it. When i added the first bone, instead of rotating it 90 degrees with R, I selected one end of the bone in edit mode and rotated/moved it that way. As i said, I'm very new to animation and rigging :D thanks.